# The getter 'notifier' isn't defined for the type 'FutureProvider<bool?>'.?

Tags: flutter, flutter-riverpod

When I user `ref.read(authLoadingProvider.notifier).update((state) => false);` like below, flutter returns error like

> The getter 'notifier' isn't defined for the type 'FutureProvider<bool?>'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'notifier', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'notifier'.dartundefined_getter

How can I fix it?

```
final authLoadingProvider = FutureProvider<bool?>((ref) async => false); 
// declared globally

void currentUserNotNull(User? user, ref) async {
  try {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await user?.reload();
    ref.read(authLoadingProvider.notifier).update((state) => false);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
//
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your helpful comment ! Reading the doc, I found that `FutureProvider<bool?>((ref) async => false); ` should not be false but to be FutureObject. So i`FutureProvider<bool?>((ref) async => SomethingReturnsFutureObjectFunction());` must be correct and `read() or watch() ` detect the changing against the FutureObject.

Comment: By the way, finally, I just want to display loading Indicator during `await user?.reload();` above my code, and felt `FutureBuilder & loading-snapshot` is not best choice and actually choose  FutureProvider. Generally how should I do display loading indicator like this simple case ?

Comment: FutureProvider is not the right tool for that. please review and understand all the riverpod providers and its differences from the official doc [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/provider)

Comment: if you want help with that, you may want to reconstruct your question, otherwise, because of how your question is constructed, we cant help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advise and I'm gonna do in that way !